# Oracle/SQL - Multijoin optimization

Tags: sql, oracle, left-join, inner-join, self-join

I'm trying to wrap my head around this multi-join problem where I have two tables

```
INTERESTED_IN
email           item
-----------------------
bob@email.com   widgetA
karen@email.com widgetA
karen@email.com widgetB
sue@email.com   widgetC
tony@email.com  widgetA
tony@email.com  widgetB
tony@email.com  widgetC


PURCHASED
email           item
-----------------------
bob@email.com   widgetA
karen@email.com widgetA
tony@email.com  widgetB
julie@email.com widgetC
```

**Objective:** To return the email and item of people who exist in the interested_in table and in the purchased table but only the items that are not in the purchased table. So the resulting table would like this

```
email           item
-----------------------
karen@email.com widgetB
tony@email.com  widgetA
tony@email.com  widgetC
```

Conceptually I know how to do this, but I'm having a very hard time wrapping my head around the most efficient way to do this as the data sets could be very large.  Can someone enlighten me on the best way to do this.

Thanks!

---

Update

```
SELECT email, item
FROM (
    SELECT i.email, i.item
    FROM interested_in i
    INNER JOIN purchased  p ON i.email = p.email
    ) 

MINUS

SELECT email, item
FROM purchased
```

Comment: Why `sue@email.com   widgetC` is not in the result set?

Answer (score 2):

Ah, I missed Sue.  So you want all the rows from the `INTERESTED_IN` table where the email exists in the `PURCHASED` table but not those rows where both the `EMAIL` and `ITEM` exists in the `PURCHASED` table.

The most obvious approach would be something like this though it would require hitting the `PURCHASED` table twice.

```
SELECT email, item
  FROM interested_in i
 WHERE EXISTS( SELECT 1
                 FROM purchased p
                WHERE i.email = p.email )
   AND NOT EXISTS( SELECT 1
                     FROM purchased p
                    WHERE i.email = p.email
                      AND i.item  = p.item )
```

or

```
SELECT email, item
  FROM interested_in i
 WHERE EXISTS( SELECT 1
                 FROM purchased p
                WHERE i.email = p.email )
MINUS
SELECT email, item
  FROM purchased
```

I'd strongly wager there is a clever way to do this while only hitting the `PURCHASED` table once though such an approach isn't immediately obvious to me.

Comment: I like the minus idea, but it returns the 'sue' record from the interested_in table and it shouldn't be.

Comment: @ypercube - D'oh!  Yup.  Missed the `AND`

Comment: I really like the idea of the minus statement.  I've always been told that using the exists is bad because the inner select will get executed once for every outer record (at least I think I recall being told that).  With that in mind how will my attempt at a solution (updated my original post) compare to your most recent solution?

Comment: `EXISTS` does not work as you describe (not always at least). Not in serious DBMS like Oracle. With proper indices, this will be fast.

Comment: @dscl - The solution you posted (which really should be an answer to your own question) will be less efficient than the `MINUS` in my answer  because the join is going to generate multiple rows that have to get filtered by the `MINUS`.  It Tony appears 3 times in `interested_in` and 4 times in `purchased`, the inner join in your solution will generate 12 rows that have to be handled in the `MINUS` rather than 4 rows if you used the `EXISTS`.  Whether the `MINUS` I provided will outperform the `NOT EXISTS` I posted depends on a number of factors.

Answer (score 1):

Probably no better than the above ...

```
select
  a.*
from
  interested_in a
  inner join (
    select distinct
      x.email
    from 
      interested_in x
      inner join purchased y
        on x.email = y.email
    ) valid_emails
    on valid_emails.email = a.email 
  left join purchased b
    on a.email = b.email
    and a.item = b.item
where
  b.email is null
;
```

result:

```
EMAIL           ITEM
tony@email.com  widgetA
tony@email.com  widgetC
karen@email.com widgetB
```

Answer (score 0):

Minus way should be more efficient. Thrd way full join where purchased.item is null

Comment: I like the minus idea, but with the way Justin suggested it returns the 'sue' record from the interested_in table and it shouldn't be.

Comment: Interestingly, `MINUS` appears to be less efficient than `EXISTS`/`NOT EXISTS`. This is true whether or not the tables are indexed. See [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6c080/1/0)

Answer (score 0):

You need to select everything from the interested in table and filter out the items that people have already purchased using a left join.

```
select * from 
   INTERESTED_IN I left join PURCHASED P 
   on I.EMAIL=P.EMAIL and I.ITEM=P.ITEM
where P.EMAIL is null
```

The intermediate table representing the query above is:

```
I.EMAIL         I.ITEM   P.EMAIL         P.ITEM
------------------------------------------------
bob@email.com   widgetA  bob@email.com   widgetA
karen@email.com widgetA  karen@email.com widgetA
karen@email.com widgetB  
sue@email.com   widgetC
tony@email.com  widgetA
tony@email.com  widgetB  tony@email.com  widgetB
tony@email.com  widgetC
```

Comment: I thought so too at first but this is incorrect. The requirement that breaks is "return the email and item of people who exist in the interested_in table **and in the purchased table**". Sue does not appear in the `Purchased` table.